# Magento Observer And Email Template

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, email-templates, html

I've created a notification email for new order to my supplier directly after the invoice is created. I receive the email but it is empty for information to grab from magento like order id and other. Can you help me pls to understand why. This Are my 2 file, the observer:

```
<?php
class Electricjesus_Notifyowner_Model_Observer
{
    public function notifyOwnerEvent($observer)
    {

        // parameters you can get from the $observer parameter:
        // array(’payment’ ? $this, ‘invoice’ ? $invoice)

        $payment = $observer->getPayment();
        $invoice = $observer->getInvoice();


        // derivative data
        $order = $invoice->getOrder(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Order



        $ownerEmail = 'test@gmail.com';
        $Subject = 'Oggetto :';
        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->loadDefault('order_copy_for_supplier');
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Prova di Ordine Confermato dopo pagamento');
        $emailTemplate->setToName($senderName);
        $emailTemplate->setToEmail($ownerEmail);
        $emailTemplate->setBody($processedTemplate);
        $emailTemplate->setSubject($Subject);
        $emailTemplate->setFromEmail($senderEmail);
        $emailTemplate->setFromName($senderName);
         $emailTemplate->setType('html');

        // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
        $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

       //Getting the Store E-Mail Sender Name.
        $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');



        //Getting the Store General E-Mail.
        $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
        $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
        $emailTemplateVariables['order_data'] = $order->getCreatedAtFormated();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);   
        $emailTemplate->send($ownerEmail, $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);

        //$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
        //$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email')
        //->setToName($senderName)
        //->setToEmail($ownerEmail)
        //->setBody($processedTemplate)
        //->setSubject($Subject)
         //->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
         //->setFromName($senderName)
         //->setType('html');
         //try{
         //Confimation E-Mail Send
         //$mail->send();
         //}
         //catch(Exception $error)
         //{
         //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($error->getMessage());
         //return false;
         //}


        return $this;  // always return $this.
    }
```

and the html file:

```
<!--@subject {{var store.getFrontendName()}}: Nuovo Ordine Per Fornitore # {{var order.increment_id}} @--><!--@vars
    {"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
    "var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
    "var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
    "htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()":"Customer Name",
    "var store.getFrontendName()":"Store Name",
    "store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",
    "var order.increment_id":"Order Id",
    "var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')":"Order Created At (datetime)",
    "var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')":"Billing Address",
    "var payment_html":"Payment Details",
    "var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')":"Shipping Address",
    "var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description",
    "layout handle=\"sales_email_order_items\" order=$order":"Order Items Grid",
    "var order.getEmailCustomerNote()":"Email Order Note"}
    @--><!--@styles@-->{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
    {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="email-heading">
                        <h1>Nuovo ordine da produrre {{var store.getFrontendName()}}.</h1>
                        <p>Gentile Fornitore, vi preghiamo di mettere in produzione il seguente ordine. Abbiamo già effettuato bonifico per la corrispondente somma a voi dovuta secondo la scontistica del 60+10 sul vostro listino. Vi preghiamo, effettuata la spedizione di inviarci il codice di tracking. Grazie.</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="store-info">
                        <h4>Info da inviare a </h4>
                        <p>
                            {{depend store_phone}}
                            <b>Chiamaci:</b>
                            <a href="tel:{{var phone}}">{{var store_phone}}</a><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_hours}}
                            <span class="no-link">{{var store_hours}}</span><br>
                            {{/depend}}
                            {{depend store_email}}
                            <b>Email:</b> <a href="mailto:{{var store_email}}">{{var store_email}}</a>
                            {{/depend}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="order-details">
            <h3>Ns. Ordine N. <span class="no-link">#{{var order.increment_id}}</span></h3>
            <p>Effettuato il {{var order.getCreatedAtFormated('long')}}</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="order-information">
        <td>
            {{if order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="message-container">
                <tr>
                    <td>{{var order.getEmailCustomerNote()}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Fattura a:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="address-details">
                        <h6>Spedizione a:</h6>
                        <p><span class="no-link">{{var order.getShippingAddress().format('html')}}</span></p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    {{depend order.getIsNotVirtual()}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Metodo di spedizione:</h6>
                        <p>{{var order.shipping_description}}</p>
                    </td>
                    {{/depend}}
                    <td class="method-info">
                        <h6>Metodo di pagamento:</h6>
                        {{var payment_html}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass the **order array** so he can get the values. so in  `TemplateVariables` add `$emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order;`

```
        $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order;
        $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
        $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
        $emailTemplateVariables['order_data'] = $order->getCreatedAtFormated();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);   
        $emailTemplate->send($ownerEmail, $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
```

Comment: OK now I've information, but I Need to understand how to insert also Items. I need some other variables? Where can i see a list of all possible variables?

Comment: If you want to add order item copy code sale order new email template copy that code in your template it will work

Comment: I've yet copied the template from new order template.

Comment: @BigBlack go to `Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` and check method **queueNewOrderEmail**

Comment: I'm sorry man but I don't understand. I have searched the method you say, but it seems not to have an item call inside.. If I try to set the template standard, the new order one, instead of a new one html, I've a blank email result.

Comment: I've this line in the order html template. But there is no table the contain it. Maybe this the problem?  `{{/if}}
            {{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}`

Comment: @BigBlack create you own item  block and call it. it is easy solution

Comment: I've inserted this ` {{block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml"}}` but seems email stop to work

Comment: No, they work, but still not seeing items